# Disagreement between glib and gcc after gcc downgrade

Tags: manjaro, gcc, glib

I updated my distro a week ago `Linux *** 5.10.41-1-MANJARO x86_64 GNU/Linux`
recent *gcc and gcc-lib* version `11.1.0`
But need to work with `gcc    10.2.0` and its coworker `gcc-libs    10.2.0`

I downgraded `gcc` and `glib` according to this [guide](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Downgrading_packages)

There is no problem with this but other thing get break like *Firefox, Chromium etc*
and it gives the following error

```
firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox/firefox)
```

How can I downgrade *gcc* and coworker libs which I think its *glib*

I don't know how to deal with *glib*

```
sudo downgrade glib-
glib-compile-resources  glib-genmarshal         glib-mkenums
glib-compile-schemas    glib-gettextize
```

Should I downgrade a *glib* thing belongs to them?

Comment: Nowadays, you just fire a container running older software (older gcc etc) so the host doesn't get this kind of problem. Btw, don't confuse gcc-libs, glibc2 or stdlibc++ with [GLib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib).

Comment: @A.B I think your comment has all that an answer would need (maybe with a few words on why firefox now won't work)

Comment: From the link: *Warning: Downgrading packages will almost always leave you in an unsupported partial upgrade state. These instructions are intended for advanced users who understand the consequences of downgrading packages* I'll strongly recommend you roll back your downgrad, maxemilian.

Comment: Good idea, yeah I have problem with them @A.B

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly, I did, it turned to more complex I think

Comment: it really isn't; people used to do prefixes and if very complex chroots for decades, but with the advent of containers, having a little isolated environment for your special-needs programs is pretty easy. A simple `sudo pacman -S podman` and you can do things like `podman run -it -v /home/maxemilian:/data:Z manjarolinux/base` and get  cozy little system in a box that you can modify to your heart's delight without damaging your main system!

Comment: I'm pretty new to Linux and this sounds very interesting. Would you mind linking some useful resources where I could learn how to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to states:

> Warning: Downgrading packages will almost always leave you in an unsupported partial upgrade state. These instructions are intended for advanced users who understand the consequences of downgrading packages

and that's exactly what happened here; you've now got dependencies (probably not even glibc, but others) that aren't compatible with your currently installed software. So, you had to roll back.

As A.B said:

> Nowadays, you just fire a container running older software (older gcc etc) so the host doesn't get this kind of problem. Btw, don't confuse gcc-libs, glibc2 or stdlibc++ with GLib.

Now, on manjaro you can use `docker` or `podman`; both do the same thing: run *containers*, which are essentially Linux systems "in a box", nicely isolated from the rest of your system. `podman` is slightly more modern, and runs better without root privileges, but supports the same commands and options as docker (where that's possible).

For example, after installing podman (`sudo pacman -S podman`) you can run

```
podman run --name myfirstcontainer -it  -v /home/maxemilian:/data:Z manjarolinux/base
```

and it will download and `run` a [manjaro image](https://hub.docker.com/r/manjarolinux/base), give you an interactive shell on it (`-it`), bind what you have under `/home/maxemilian` as `v`olume visible in the container as `/data` (using your own ownerships `Z`). Your container persists after exit (check `podman ps -a`), and can be started again using `podman start --attach myfirstcontainer`.

You can do the downgrade *within* that container, and not touch anything outside. Through the volume, your container can access the source files you need to compile!

It's very common to run a `distcc` as "server" compiler inside the container. You need to add `--publish 3632` for that to work, and, on your development machine (i.e. your "normal" manjaro), instead of using e.g. `gcc` as compiler, use `distcc`.

podman run -it --publish 3632 --name buildserver manjarolinux/base
#install gcc, distcc
distccd --daemon

Try! Make a file `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("GCC %d.%d.%d", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__, __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__);
  return 0;
}
```

Run

```
export CC=distcc
export DISTCC_HOSTS=localhost
$CC -o test test.c
./test
```

Comment: Could you share `/etc/containers/registries.conf` setting I can't fetch the image. I added some combination of regitry but its giving `Error: error loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf": toml: cannot load TOML value of type map[string]interface {} into a Go slice` like those things